# tokenizing with matching list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, tokenize

I am working with chemical compounds names.I used to DCG rules to define the name format.but the input is a list format,that not a good way.because the elements separate by separater.but i want as one string input like `"1-butene"` it is send as `['1','-',but,ene]` .my code is here.

`stem11-->[but]|[pent]|[hex]|[hept].`
`suf --> [ene]|[yne].`
`seperater-->['-'].`
`numerals-->['1']|['2']|['3']|['4']|['5']|['6']|['7'].`
`main-->numerals,seperater,stem11,suf.`
`check(S):-tokenize(S,L),main(L,[]).`
here
`tokenize("1-butene",L).`
`L=['1','-',but,ene].`
i want the tokenizing code the input may be like `[1-butene]`.i tried many ways but couldn't get the proper code.please help me.

Comment: Please improve both the style and the content of your question! How? Use a spell checker ("separater" => "separator", "i" => "I") and a grammar checker ("my rules like below."). Care about proper indentation and punctuation ("cant", "... separater.but i want ..."). Avoid making multiple errors in one sentence ("I used to DCG rules to define the name format."), which only gets understandable, sort of, after reading it multiple times and considering phonetic similarities. In short: please put more effort into writing, reach more people, and get more and better answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try my answer,Here my input like`"1-butene"`
`stem11-->[but]|[pent]|[hex]|[hept].`
`suf --> [ene]|[yne].`
`seperater-->['-'].`
`numerals-->['1']|['2']|['3']|['4']|['5']|['6']|['7'].`
`main-->numerals,seperater,stem11,suf.`

`:-set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).`
`any(A,K) --> {member(S,K)}, S, {atom_codes(A, S)}.`
`words(A)    --> any(A,["but","pent","hex","hept","ene","yne","-","1","2","3"]).`
`split([])     --> "".`
`split([X|Xs]) --> words(X), split(Xs).`
`tokenize(S,L):-phrase(split(L),S).`
`check(S):-tokenize(S,L),main(L,[]).`
query like this.
`?- tokenize("1-butene",L).`
`L = ['1', -, but, ene] ;`
`?- check("1-butene").`
`true ;`

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, I would do tokenization inline:

```
stem11    -->"but"|"pent"|"hex"|"hept".
suf       -->"ene"|"yne".
seperator -->"-".
numerals  -->"1"|"2". % etc
main      -->numerals,seperator,stem11,suf.
```

then use `?- phrase(main, "1-butene").` or `?- main("1-butene", []).`

*edit*

```
stem11(A)    --> atom(["but","pent","hex","hept"], A).
suf(A)       --> atom(["ene","yne"], A).
separator(-) -->"-".
numerals(A)  --> atom(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"], A).

atom(L, A) --> {member(S, L)}, atom_match(S), {atom_codes(A, S)}.
atom_match([]) --> [].
atom_match([C|Cs]) --> [C], atom_match(Cs).

tokenize([A,B,C,D]) --> numerals(A), separator(B), stem11(C), suf(D).

check(S,L) :- phrase(tokenize(L), S, []).
```

yields (tested with GnuProlog)

```
?- check("1-butene",L).
L = ['1',-,but,ene] ?
```

Comment: This is ok. but i used list format for other uses.so i want in list format.

Comment: I Used Swiprolog.how to run it

Comment: Thanks For your ideas.Using your idea i can get the answer.thanks again.